# Методы с работой VK .api.audio?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Подскажите где найти методы для работы VK .api.audio? На официальном сайте все удаленно. А мне нужен метод audio.getbyid а точней как с ним работать (Документация). Задача следующая. Через web.socket я буду отправлять id записи!!! А у другого пользователя. Эта-же запись будет доставаться с применением его токена(ТАК КАК ВСЕ АУДИО ЗАПИСИ ПРИВЯЗАНЫ К IP) нужно описание самого метода!

P.S Прошу не писать что публичный API в VK закрыты в 2016 году ниже приведу пример как получить токен для публичного API и запрос audio.get по тому как помню его по памяти!!!

Токен получаю с помощью этого приложения:

```
<?php
$client_id = '5456066';
$scope = 'offline,audio';
$new_url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?сient_id=$client_id&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=$scope&response_type=token&v=5.37";
header('Location: '.$new_url);
?>
```

Пример работы audio.get:

```
<?php
$acces_token="ТОКЕН";
$json = curl('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=[ID пользователя]&need_user=0&count=1000&offset=0&access_token='.$acces_token.'&v=5.62');
$st = json_decode($json, true);
function curl($url)
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $response;
}
?>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">"<?var_dump($st);?>"</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен!!! Нашел по архивам тут [Архив сайтов](https://web.archive.org/web/20150120020716/http://vk.com/dev/audio.get)

По идентификатору находит

```
<?php
 $acces_token="ТОКЕН";
 $json = curl('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=[ID пользователя]&audio_ids=[ID трека]&need_user=0&count=1000&offset=0&access_token='.$acces_token.'&v=5.62);
 function curl($url)
 {
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) 
Presto/2.2.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $response;
   }
   ?>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">"<?var_dump($st);?>"</pre>
```